# Custom checkbox validation on submit

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

I have the code below which is working as expected. It is doing a form validation with Vue.js and [Vee-Validate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate). It is checking that at least one checkbox is checked.

I only don't like that I have to manually call validate for oneChecked-Validator on form submission. With-out the call it's not validating on submit.

It would be great if someone could review my code and give me an advice to the following points:

- How can I configure Vee Validator so that it evaluates the oneChecked validator with the call of `this.$validator.validateAll();`?
- Is it possible to pass the `this.options` array into validate method of oneChecked validator? (Would be more re-usable. I've tried passing as array with `JSON.stringify` but couldn't get it to work.)

If there is more to improve please let me know. I'm using Vee-Validate for the first time.

You can also find the same code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pndvq438/).

```js
const Checkboxes = {
  template: '#checkboxTmpl',
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      options: [{
        id: 0,
        checked: false
      }, {
        id: 1,
        checked: false
      }, {
        id: 2,
        checked: false
      }]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$validator.extend('oneChecked', {
      getMessage: field => 'At least one ' + field + ' needs to be checked.',
      validate: (value, [testProp]) => {
        const options = this.options;
        // console.log('questions', value, testProp, options.some((option) => option[testProp]));
        return value || options.some((option) => option[testProp]);
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    validateBeforeSubmit(e) {
      this.$validator.validateAll(); // why is oneChecked not validated here? --> manually trigger validate below
      this.options.forEach((option) => {
        this.$validator.validate('check0', option.checked, ['checked'])
      });

      console.log('validator', this.errors);
      if (!this.errors.any()) {
        alert('succesfully submitted!');
      }
    }
  }
};

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: (h) => h(Checkboxes)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vee-validate/2.0.0-beta.18/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.8/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

</div>

<script id="checkboxTmpl" type="text/template">
  <form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
    <input v-model="text" name="text" v-validate.initial="text" data-vv-rules="required|min:3" placeholder="required input" />
    <p v-show="errors.has('text')">{{ errors.first('text') }}</p>
    <br/>

    <label v-for="(option, index) in options">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="option.checked" name="check0" v-validate.initial="option.checked" data-vv-rules="oneChecked:checked" data-vv-as="checkbox" />Checkbox {{index}}
    </label>
    <p v-show="errors.has('check0')">{{ errors.first('check0') }}</p>
    <pre>{{options}}</pre>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I configure Vee Validator so that it evaluates the oneChecked validator with the call of this.$validator.validateAll();?

Yes, you can use `validateAll()`, you're just not passing the fields for it to validate. Here's an example on how to do this:

```
methods: {
  validateBeforeSubmit(e) {
    this.$validator.validateAll({
      name0: true
    });
    console.log('validator', this.errors);
    if (!this.errors.any()) {
      alert('succesfully submitted!');
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/144).

> Is it possible to pass the this.options array into validate method of oneChecked validator? (Would be more re-usable. I've tried passing as array with JSON.stringify but couldn't get it to work.)

Why pass it as a parameter when it's already a constant?

Consider this:

```
created() {
  this.$validator.extend('oneChecked', {
    getMessage: field => 'At least one ' + field + ' needs to be checked.',
    validate: (value, [testProp]) => {
      return value || Checkboxes.data().options.some((option) => option[testProp]);
    }
  });
},
```

This also provides you some protection for when data().options inevitably has more than 3 elements in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way with `validateAll` to pass a reference name was new for me and it simplifies code because I can create a map for all checkbox groups and pass it to validateAll. That's easier than calling `validate` with all parameters. But it breaks the validation of text input - not sure why (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pndvq438/1/)). Also what does the `true` mean inside the passed object? I had to pass `false` to make the validation work. In my demo it's working by accessing the constant but I'd like to have it more flexible. (that's OK now -see fiddle)

Comment: @AWolf I have the same problem like u, and I think I am missing some information. I asked my question on github: https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1674
Maybe you can share some insights on the questions I asked there:
Most important: why is my rule not validated anyway? Why do we need something like your `validateBeforeSubmit`. 
Thank you in advance.